# Java - ThreadPool with two queues. Or two queues in one

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpool

Short version - I'm looking for the most efficient way to wrap two queues into one for use in a thread pool where priority is given to the content of one of the queues as long as it is non-empty and then falling back to the second queue.

Long version:
Several thread pools in system, each with their own queue.

"External" requests come from the outside and are submitted to one of the pools where it is processed for a while and then transferred to another queue. After the first transfer the request is considered "Internal" until it is completed. The request may be transferred between all thread pools and may end up in the one it started in.

What I want to do is if the queue for each thread pool contains Internal requests, they should be processed first until the queue runs out of Internal requests, then it should switch to External ones. If a new Internal shows up, then that should be processed next.

Do not need pure FIFO, currently using one LinkedTransferQueue per thread pool because this is the fastest kind-of-FIFO queue I've found when it comes to many consumers and many producers. Very high insertion rates and the spinlock in LinkedTransferQueue works amazingly well.

Size of queues are handled elsewhere (as are rejections), so I really only need proper put/take behavior.

Past attempts at solutions that did not work out:

1. PriorityBlockingQueue - Too slow. Locks are bad, especially on my hardware for some reason. (2.4 ghz quad core laptop almost outperforms 2x 2.0ghz hexa-core server)
2. Manually wrapping two LinkedBlockingQueue - Worked fine, but was also too slow. Using ONE LinkedBlockingQueue is also too slow.
3. Manually wrapping two ArrayBlockingQueue - Same as LinkedBlockingQueue.

Thoughts on solution:

- Manually "merging" two LinkedTransferQueues... but after looking at
  the code for it I'm afraid I'm not smart enough to do that without
  breaking something.
- Spinning for a while, doing a peek() on both queues until I find something... This is basically a spinlock, and I guess I could do this for a while, but I think I'd want the same behaviour as LinkedTransferQueue, that is. Spin for a while, then yield or sleep for a while. But I have no way of waking up. (EDIT: I'd really prefer if I could avoid "real" locks)

Can't just do a peek() on External and if null block on Internal instead, because something might be inserted into External and I'll be blocked waiting on Internal. I'll never unblock from Internal since things can't end up in Internal unless I process them in from External... Same way if I turn it 180 degrees (except it'll come from inside the system)

My apologies for a post that makes no sense...

Comment: Just a thought, but if you do the peek and block as you suggest near the end, and then on insert check for empty queues and insert external to the internal queue in that case, then it could work.  You would need careful synchronization or perhaps good management of an atomic boolean in order to avoid issues though, so that might push the performance below the blocking queue approaches.

Comment: That could work... AtomicBoolean is CAS so it should be a lot faster.. doing a LOT of AtomicInteger++'s in the code as is, and it hasn't slowed it down noticeably.

EDIT: Wont be able to try til monday... :)

Comment: You could use CyclicBarrier and keep it updated according to appropriate queue counts. But it may also be slow ...

Comment: Another option, you could copy the code from LinkedTransferQueue and make your own version, that takes a second fallback queue in the constructor and then in the private xfer and awaitMatch methods, you could peek at this second queue as well to exit out of the spin.  I am not sure what the copyright concerns of doing this are though.

Comment: CyclicBarrier is unfortunately out due to locks.
I've considered modifying LinkedTransferQueue.. but.. I feel sooo stupid when I look at that code. (Its public domain, so copyright is not an issue).

Currently playing with AtomicBooleans, but the xfer/awaitMatch way might be the way to go.

Comment: I took a brief glance at LinkedTransferQueue, and I think all you would need to do is add a check (and conditional return) to peek at the second queue in awaitMatch before `if (spins < 0)`. Although, there might be some maintenance you need to do to keep the object consistent, but I didn't see it.

Comment: I think I need to do something about the LockSupport.park/unpark. Its parked in awaitMatch and unparked in xfer. If i'm parked and do a put into the "internal" queue, then I'm not sure it'd wake up.

Comment: Although if I do get something back from poll/peek I might get away with doing LockSupport.unpark(Thread.currentThread())... but I'm just guessing.

EDIT: Or not, since p.waiter may be another thread than my own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried another approach with one queue feeding another and blocking when there are too many "internal" requests being processed... the lock cut performance in half.

In the end I ended up doing this:
Put two LinkedTransferQueues in a class that implements BlockingQueue.
Have the "offer" method decide what queue it ends up in and the take method do the following (not exact code):

```
@Override
public Runnable take() throws InterruptedException {
    int c = 0;
    ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    while (true) {
        // Check internal first
        Runnable r = internalQueue.poll();
        if (r != null) {
            return r;
        }

        // Spin for a while on external, with occasional yield.
        while(c < 128)
        {
            r = externalQueue.poll();
            if (r != null) {
                return r;
            }

            if(rand.nextInt(32) == 0)
            {
                Thread.yield();
            }

            c++;
        }

        // Use the transfer queues time limited poll.
        r = externalQueue.poll(10000, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        if (r != null) {
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Believe it or not, this actually increased throughput by 15% and cut latency in half. Less "started but not finished" requests eating up resources and probably a tiny bit less contention in the queues (due to my usage scenario).

The values and the idea of the spinlock was taken from the code of LinkedTransferQueue.

The downside is that with the above code the system idles at 11%, but that is easily fixed by increasing the poll timeout after 30 seconds of inactivity.

Still welcoming a better solution if anyone happens to run into one some day, but for now this works.